# Associate MAC Address with IP Address?

Tags: router, dhcp, osx-yosemite

I would like to forward some ports on my router to specific devices on my home network. To do this, I would like the desktop computers at my home to have fixed IP addresses on my local network. Other computers and devices should just use DHCP. All of the devices connect to my modem (a Motorola SURFboard eXtreme) over Wifi.

I have heard that the way to do this is to set up the modem for DHCP and then change the settings on the devices that should have the specific IP addresses.

I attempted to do this by going into:

System Preferences > Network > Wi-Fi > Advanced... > TCP/IP

and changing Configure IPv4 to Using DHCP with manual address and setting the IPv4 Address to the currently unused 192.168.0.250. Apply the settings and my computer loses its connection to the network entirely.

So I feel like this isn't something that needs to be changed locally, but that this is something that should be handled by the modem/router. The problem is, I don't see anything in the UI for the router to change this.

If I am correct that this needs to be changed on the router and I can't change it via the UI, I feel like surely my modem is nothing more than a little Linux computer running a web server on port 80 (for the UI) and routing traffic... is it not possible to just SSH in and change a configuration file in `etc` or something and modify settings not exposed by the UI? (IDK, I've never heard of this kind of thing before, but I feel like this is probably how the magic box called a model/router really works.)

Alternatively, I'd like to make it so that in the modem's port forwarding, it forwards to a specific MAC address instead of an IP Address.

Comment: What's the subnet mask of the DHCP/router as this will determine how many devices your router will service.

Comment: 255.255.255.000... as I recall this means it can support 256 different devices, right?

Answer (score 1):

With many routers, the web user interface permits the assignment of static/persistent DHCP addresses. If you are able to find the web page on your router that allows such configuration, that will probably be the easiest. You basically pair a MAC address to an IP address via the interface under the routers handling of DHCP.

For instance I run a router on which I have installed the 3rd party firmware Tomato. The settings under my version of Tomato can be found at Basic -> Static-DHCP. There I associate a MAC address with an IP and save. The page also lists the current static DHCP assignments. So I change nothing on my systems. They are setup for use with DHCP and the router just assigns them the same IP each time. For some systems a reboot may be the easiest way to have things take effect after you save.

Comment: Tomato doesn't appear to be available for my router. (Motorola SURFboard eXtreme.)

Comment: My router's model number is SBG6580.

Comment: Do you have the Motorola sbg6580? (ok you do) Others may be the same. I've read/heard on this one at least that under  Basic -> DHCP next to your computer (either identified based on mac or IP) select and then select add where it says Reserve New IP Address. Here is is referred to as a "reserved IP address" instead of "static DHCP IP." It's possible that your modem/router doesn't support this, but many do.

Comment: Okay, I used that setting. I feel like I've used this before though... I think it loses these every time I reset the router. Is there a way I can keep that from happening?

Comment: Resetting the router/modem, makes me think of resetting it to its factory defaults. If that is what is being done, then no. There may be an option to save the current configuration to a file and then manually load it later after the reset. When things are working properly one doesn't typically reset the modem/router very often.

Comment: About once a month it loses its connection to my ISP so I unplug it and plug it back in. I was hoping it would write it to a hard drive or something but now I'm wondering if it even has any onboard storage... it has to, because I know my ISP has modified its firmware before.

Comment: You might contact your ISP regarding the need to unplug every month. If after making changes to your modem/router, you're hitting apply (or the equivalent thereof), then typically this would be saved across power outages. You might check with your ISP on this as well, particularly if you are renting the device from them.